# Cannot send email via smtp.office365.com ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp, office365, smtpclient

I've read a lot of blogs & tutorials on this subject, but it still doesn't work. I'm attempting to send email using Office365's SMTP server.

This is my code

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;  
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EmailAddress", "Password", "domain.com");
smtpClient.Port = 587; // 25 587
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Timeout = 600000;

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("fromemailaddress", "Enquiry");
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("toemailaddress", "Test"));
mailMessage.Subject = "Inquiry";
mailMessage.Body = "\r\nName:" + user.Name + "\r\nMessage:" + user.Message
                   + "\r\nContact No.:" + user.MobileNo + "\r\nEmail Address:" + user.Email;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

I got an exception:

> Unable to connect to the remote server
> Failure sending mail.
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 51.92.122.216:587

I am a newbie in this. I try to ping the domain it's listening and I successfully login in the browser with same credentials.

Anything I am missing to set up after login via Office 365?

Thank you

Comment: make sure you setting same as in given link         
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

Comment: I set up the exact hostname, port, and credentials. anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good, and as long as you have followed [these](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353) guides (correct host and ports). You should be fine.

But be aware, smtp is disabled by default, and you have to enable it for your account.

Also if you have configured MFA (so a token or a text) you’re out off luck, since it won’t accept your password. If that is the case you need to create a special `app password` as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944).